# Cloudfront Redirect using Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using Terraform to create a Cloudfront distribution. I have it up and running, but the only way I can access it is through the `https://<id>.cloudfront.net/` address. I'd like to use a record in the Route 53 zone I have to redirect to the Cloudfront distribution. Any Idea how to do this?

```
variable "www_domain_name" {
  default = "example.com"
}
```

An S3 bucket is used to host the static code. This is available to the public and uses a policy that allows for public access.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "www" {
  bucket = var.www_domain_name
  acl    = "public-read"
  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::${var.www_domain_name}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
  website {
    index_document = "index.html"
    error_document = "404.html"
  }
}
```

AWS Certificate Manager is used to create the SSL certificate for the domain. This may take a long time to apply and requires you to confirm it with your email address.

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "certificate" {
  domain_name       = "*.${var.root_domain_name}"
  validation_method = "EMAIL"
  subject_alternative_names = [ var.root_domain_name ]
}
```

AWS Cloudfront is used to distribute the load of the website to Amazon's edge locations.

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "www_distribution" {
  /**
   * The distribution's origin needs a "custom" setup in order to redirect 
   * traffic from <domain>.com to www.<domain>.com. The values bellow are the 
   * defaults.
   */
  origin {
    custom_origin_config {
      http_port              = "80"
      https_port             = "443"
      origin_protocol_policy = "http-only"
      origin_ssl_protocols   = ["TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"]
    }

    /** 
     * This connects the S3 bucket created earlier to the Cloudfront 
     * distribution. 
     */
    domain_name = aws_s3_bucket.www.website_endpoint
    origin_id   = var.www_domain_name
  }

  enabled             = true
  default_root_object = "index.html"

  default_cache_behavior {
    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    compress               = true
    allowed_methods        = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods         = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id       = var.www_domain_name
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 86400
    max_ttl                = 31536000

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false
      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * This sets the aliases of the Cloudfront distribution. Here, it is being
   * set to be accessible by <var.www_domain_name>.
   */
  aliases = [ var.www_domain_name ]

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }

  /**
   * The AWS ACM Certificate is then applied to the distribution.
   */
  viewer_certificate {
    acm_certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.certificate.arn
    ssl_support_method  = "sni-only"
  }
}
```

The Route 53 Zone needs to be created so that its nameservers can point to the Cloudfront Distribution.

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "zone" {
  name = var.root_domain_name
}
```

This is the Route 53 Record that redirects to the Cloudfront Distribution.

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id
  name    = var.www_domain_name
  type    = "A"

  alias {
    name                   = aws_cloudfront_distribution.www_distribution.domain_name
    zone_id                = aws_cloudfront_distribution.www_distribution.hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

Comment: What issue do you have when you've applied that all out? At a glance that looks right to me.

Comment: The issue is that when I visit the url in Safari, there is no page. When I visit the url cloud front gives me, I see the page. I’d imagine there’s an issue with the Route 53 redirect.

Comment: No page as in nothing loads or no page as in there's an error? If so what does the error show and have you attempted to debug that in any way?

Comment: No page as in nothing loads. No error, just doesn’t load anything. The cloud front url works great. I’d like to redirect the www.domain.com to the cloudfront url.

Comment: Are you willing/able to share the domain? It sounds hard to debug without seeing what issue you are seeing.

Comment: Sure. Better yet, I can just send you a [link](https://github.com/tnorlund/Blog-backend/blob/main/terraform/ContentDelivery/main.tf) to the file in the repo. The actual domain is www.tylernorlund.com

Comment: I just read that DNS records on Route 53 can take up to 72 hours to propagate. Does this apply to this record?

Comment: How have you created the domain? Do you actually own `tylernorlund.com`? There's no name servers at that domain so it looks like that zone is broken.

Comment: I own the domain. I’m moving away from AWS Amplify and creating my own CloudFront Distribution. All the correct records are set using the Route 53 console, and when I test for the records using Route 53, it says that they are there. Can it really take 72 hours?

Comment: `dig tylernorlund.com ns` doesn't return any name server records. How sure are you that the zone is configured correctly?

Comment: The Route 53 console shows 12 records. Some are for Workmail, others are for CloudFront and other services. I set up the hosted zone through Terraform above. Do I need to add DNSSEC signing or Hosted zone tags?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229393/discussion-between-tyler-norlund-and-ydaetskcor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some back and forth in comments and then in chat it appeared that the Route53 zone was misconfigured with missing name servers from that the domain was expecting.

After adding name server records to match what was shown by the output of `whois tylernorlund.com | grep "Name Server"` the zone was resolvable again and records were able to be resolved.

```
$ whois tylernorlund.com | grep "Name Server"
   Name Server: NS-1398.AWSDNS-46.ORG
   Name Server: NS-1571.AWSDNS-04.CO.UK
   Name Server: NS-365.AWSDNS-45.COM
   Name Server: NS-871.AWSDNS-44.NET
Name Server: ns-1398.awsdns-46.org
Name Server: ns-1571.awsdns-04.co.uk
Name Server: ns-365.awsdns-45.com
Name Server: ns-871.awsdns-44.net

$ dig tylernorlund.com any @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.14-Ubuntu <<>> tylernorlund.com any @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31196
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 11, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;tylernorlund.com.      IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
tylernorlund.com.   59  IN  A   99.86.119.38
tylernorlund.com.   59  IN  A   99.86.119.32
tylernorlund.com.   59  IN  A   99.86.119.124
tylernorlund.com.   59  IN  A   99.86.119.72
tylernorlund.com.   21599   IN  NS  ns-1398.awsdns-46.org.
tylernorlund.com.   21599   IN  NS  ns-1571.awsdns-04.co.uk.
tylernorlund.com.   21599   IN  NS  ns-365.awsdns-45.com.
tylernorlund.com.   21599   IN  NS  ns-871.awsdns-44.net.
tylernorlund.com.   899 IN  SOA ns-365.awsdns-45.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
tylernorlund.com.   599 IN  MX  10 inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
tylernorlund.com.   299 IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all"

;; Query time: 54 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Mar 03 10:21:44 GMT 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 402
```